# Zissin Pesach - Where does this phrase come from?

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, chagim-holidays, social-convention

What is the history of wishing a zissin - sweet Pesach? Was this purposely created, as someone once told me, in contrast to wishing a Chag kosher vesameach?

Comment: http://forward.com/culture/13161/a-sweet-passover-for-all-01669/

Comment: Just thinking about this again.  Thank you for this link.